# A comprehensive book on Applied Mathematics for beginners

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, applications, book-recommendation

The Princeton Companion To Mathematics is described on Wikipedia thus:

> The book concentrates primarily on modern pure mathematics rather than applied mathematics, although it does also cover both applications of mathematics and the mathematics that relates to those applications; it provides a broad overview of the significant ideas and developments in research mathematics. It is organized into eight parts:

Although this book includes **Applied Mathematics**, can any one recommend a comprehensive beginners book on Applied Mathematics ?

Comment: Introduction to Applied Mathematics by Gilbert Strang.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to expand a little on @lhf's comment recommending [Introduction to Applied Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0961408804) by Gilbert Strang. Whether it is appropriate for beginners depends on your precise definition of beginner - I would recommend background in linear algebra, multivariable calculus and differential equations at the very least before reading it. Where it excels is in setting up and introducing a unified framework for a large swath of applied mathematics based on equilibrium equations and minimum principles (see chapters 1-3, especially chapter 2). The table of contents can be found at http://www-math.mit.edu/~gs/books/itam_toc.html. The topics cover much of traditional and contemporary applied mathematics, including optimization. However, the book makes no claims to being encyclopedic.

See also Strang's more recent [Computational Science and Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0961408812). There's a table of contents for this book at http://math.mit.edu/~gs/cse/.

Answer (score 1):

Applied Mathematics for Engineers and Physicists by Louis A. Pipes and Lawrence R. Harvill

Amazon.com quote:

> One of the most widely used reference books on applied mathematics for
>   a generation, distributed in multiple languages throughout the world,
>   this text is geared toward use with a one-year advanced course in
>   applied mathematics for engineering students. The treatment assumes a
>   solid background in the theory of complex variables and a familiarity
>   with complex numbers, but it includes a brief review. Chapters are as
>   self-contained as possible, offering instructors flexibility in
>   designing their own courses. The first eight chapters explore the
>   analysis of lumped parameter systems. Succeeding topics include
>   distributed parameter systems and important areas of applied
>   mathematics. Each chapter features extensive references for further
>   study as well as challenging problem sets. Answers and hints to select
>   problem sets are included in an Appendix. This edition includes a new
>   Preface by Dr. Lawrence R. Harvill.